# Offline Encryption/Decrytpion without storing the private key? Is it possible?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have a question on the limitations of cryptography. May seem like a stupid question. I apologise in advance.

This is for a client which I myself am trying to wrap my head around it.

The information will be encrypted and then encoded in an accessible format e.g. QR or barcode. Decryption is using the application our developers are creating. The problem is that the application would be offline majority of the time when it is in used as the users would be in areas that have either intermittent or poor reception. So to be able to decrypt it, the application has to have the private key present on the device itself, correct? Would this even be a good solution? Even the developers have concerns on having all the apps offline with the same private key present. Note that the application will be used by multiple groups.

Is there an alternative that I can explore that any of you can suggest where we don't have to store the private key but still manage to secure the information for offline use? So far I've look into DRM for restricting copying information but not sure how it would help. I'm also willing to look into other solutions for this.

*The database holding the information would be updated when they have an internet connection. I'm only assuming on this part since I'm not handling this part of the project.*

Please and thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the right way but found a suitable path.

Using a combination of asymmetric key and symmetric key where the symmetric key is used to decrypt data on the offline device. Asymmetric is used to encrypt the data. The asymmetric keys is only exchange when the devices are in need to be sync'd. This would put the trust on the devices itself so I'm not worried on this.

This idea came from [Sectigo - Why Automotive Key Fob Encryption Hacks Are Making Headlines?](https://sectigo.com/resource-library/why-automotive-key-fob-encryption-hacks-are-making-headlines)